# How to normalize/transform the XML data using xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am new to XSLT and Need help in transforming the data to show:
Need to order the skill ascending  by Employee ID and show the data like attached screenshot.
If we have 20 skills, all 20 skills should be mapped to employee id.

and also if first 20 chars of skill name is the same then we should treat that as only one skill.

Input xml is like this:

```
<wd:Report_Data xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/Worker_Skills_Data">
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>100006949</wd:empid>
        <wd:name>Brooke</wd:name>
        <wd:status>Active</wd:status>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Assisting First Time Home Buyers</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Banking</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Credit</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Leadership</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Lending</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Loan Origination</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Mortgage Banking</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Mortgage Lending</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Negotiation</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Real Estate</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Real Estate Investments</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Refinancing</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Residential Homes</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Residential Mortgages</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Reverse Mortgages</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Sales</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Sales Management</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>VA Lending</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:empid>100002194</wd:empid>
        <wd:name>Troy</wd:name>
        <wd:status>Active</wd:status>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Banking</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Credit</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Credit Analysis</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Customer Service</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Finance</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Financial Analysis</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Leadership</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Lending</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Loan Servicing</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Mortgage Banking</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Mortgage Lending</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Mortgage Servicing</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>People Management</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Process Improvements</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Risk Management</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Software Documentation</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
        <wd:skillscloud>
            <wd:skill>Underwriting</wd:skill>
        </wd:skillscloud>
    </wd:Report_Entry>
</wd:Report_Data>
```

[image: Output should be]

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) the exact expected result (as code, not as picture) and (2) your attempted XSLT.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info for some introduction and samples on grouping with XSLT 2 or 3.

Comment: Saying you need help does not make this a legitimate SO question. We're not here to write the code for you, we're here to help you get unstuck when you write it yourself and have a specific problem. From a practical perspective, if we can see your best attempt then we can see where you are on the learning curve (how much reading have you done?) and that helps to frame the answer.